Typing a map of generic functions with recursive callback in Typescript
I'm making a package that lets you define "actions" and then "trigger" them. Actions are functions that take some payload and a callback to trigger more actions recursively.
Ideally, using the package would look like:
import { ActionDef, getTrigger } from 'thePackage';

const action1 = ((payload, trigger) => {
    console.log('action1', payload)
    trigger('action2', {y: 'abc'})
}) satisfies ActionDef<MyActions, {x: number}>;

const action2 = ((payload, trigger) => {
    console.log('action2', payload)
    trigger('action1', {x: 123})
}) satisfies ActionDef<MyActions, {y: string}>;


const actions = {
    action1,
    action2
}

type MyActions = typeof actions;

const trigger = getTrigger(actions);

function triggerSomeActions() {
    trigger('action1', {x: 123});
    trigger('action1', {x: 234});
    trigger('action2', {y: 'abc'});
}

I want typescript to validate that the calls to trigger (both from getTrigger and as callbacks) are valid (valid name and valid corresponding payload).
Now this doesn't work because of the circular type reference of MyActions.
I'm wondering if there is a way to type this properly, without making it too annoying for the developer using the package.
So far these are the types I have in the package:
type ActionDef<A extends Actions, P> = (payload: P, triggerCallback: TriggerFunc<A>) => void
type Actions = Record<string, ActionDef<any, any>>;
type PayloadFromDef<D> = D extends ActionDef<any, infer P> ? P : never
type TriggerFunc<A extends Actions> = (<K extends keyof A>(actionName: K, payload: PayloadFromDef<A[K]>) => void);
declare function getTrigger<A extends Actions>(actions: A): TriggerFunc<A>;

TypeScript Playground with the whole thing

One solution to get rid of the circular type reference would be to separately list the action names and payload types, in something like:
type ActionTypes = {
  action1: {x: number};
  action2: {y: string};
}

and then use this instead of MyActions when defining the action functions, but it hurts the DevX.

I'm having a hard time seeing how you can use that ActionTypes solution to solve your problem. Could you [edit] to show how it works and how it hurts developer experience? Also, is there any way to pare the [mre] down to something requiring fewer than 60 lines of code? As soon as we have to start scrolling around to see what's going on it becomes more difficult to solve.

(see prev comment) So, this playground link shows what I'd consider a [mre] of your situation, except that I really can't understand why this isn't already the way you'd want to proceed. Your actions object is inherently circular and by far the most straightforward approach is just to give it a type to start with. Could you demonstrate why the developer experience is worse here than whatever hoops one might jump through to get TS to infer the types?

Thanks a lot @jcalz! I find the DevX annoying if you define those actions separately: in the real scenario, those action functions are actually objects containing many complex functions, and having them all defined in one big "ActionMap" is not ideal. When defining them separately, you end up with the name of each action in 3 places instead of 1 in an ideal scenario (like the one I'm trying to achieve with the broken circular dependency version). Here is a playground link where I define the actions separately.

• Could you please [edit] to make the [mre] small like the one we're talking about in the playground links? • Again, I'm not seeing how you could possibly do this much better than defining the interface and then referring to it, which sounds like 2 places to me (or 3 if you require breaking each thing up into more pieces and then putting them together).  Your data structure is inherently circular. classes have some support for such circularity but it doesn't seem like that's going to be helpful here. Honestly I imagine the answer here is "no, there's nothing better you can do".

(see prev comment, especially the part about [edit]ing).  So, the closest I can get to anything like this is to use a class declaration as shown in this playground link. Now you can get away with naming each payload type exactly once. Personally I think this is worse than just defining an interface ahead of time. Anyway, does this fully address the question? I could write up an answer if so, otherwise what am I missing about the question?

I simplified the question. Thanks for the class version. I agree with you that the previous version (defining the interface ahead) sounds like the best we can do here!

I'm really hitting problems trying to use your simplified version since you are constraining things to Actions but along the way it seems to imply that the payloads are themselves functions. Could you please quadruple check that code and then either tell me why you're writing it this way, or [edit] to something that doesn't make the functions payloads? Ideally you'd make a [mre] which shows the problem (with circularity), the solution you don't like (that works), and then we can answer with "this solution is the best way, everything else is worse".

You are right there should have been some MyActions in there. In any case I feel you have already more than answered my question. If you put your playground examples in an answer I'll gladly accept it.

The type of actions is inherently circular, and asking TypeScript to infer such a type for you isn't going to work very well. While class declarations tend to let you infer types of one property based on the inferred types of other properties, arbitrary object literals and functions don't generally work that way.
It would be much more straightforward to define a simple mapping interface from action name to payload type (e.g., your ActionTypes), and then implementing an actions object of that type. You say that's not an ideal developer experience, but it's got to better than trying to jump through circularity-avoiding hoops. Your example didn't show what this looks like, so here's what I'd say is the most reasonable implementation.
First we change your types to:
type ActionDef<AP, K extends keyof AP> =
    (payload: AP[K], triggerCallback: TriggerFunc<AP>) => void
type TriggerFunc<AP> =
    <K extends keyof AP>(actionName: K, payload: AP[K]) => void;
type ActionMap<AP> = { [K in keyof AP]: ActionDef<AP, K> }
declare function getTrigger<AP>(actions: ActionMap<AP>): TriggerFunc<AP>;

I'm not writing anything in terms of the type of the actions (A) really; it's just the types of the payloads (AP) and the keys (K). Note that you no longer need to constrain anything to an action type, nor do you need to explicitly infer anything when describing the types.  And ActionDef only needs to know about the key K of AP corresponding to the payload; it can compute the payload as AP[K].  Finally, the getTrigger() function infers AP from the mapped type ActionMap<AP> and returns TriggerFunc<AP>.
Okay, now, for a working example, we define that mapping interface ahead of time:
interface ActionTypes {
    action1: { x: number };
    action2: { y: string };
}

Then your assembly of actions happens much as before except that you use the new type definitions:
const action1 = ((payload, trigger) => {
    console.log('action1', payload)
    trigger('action2', { y: 'abc' })
}) satisfies ActionDef<ActionTypes, "action1">;

const action2 = ((payload, trigger) => {
    console.log('action2', payload)
    trigger('action1', { x: 123 })
}) satisfies ActionDef<ActionTypes, "action2">;

const actions = {
    action1,
    action2
}

const trigger = getTrigger(actions);

function triggerSomeActions() {
    trigger('action1', { x: 123 });
    trigger('action1', { x: 234 });
    trigger('action2', { y: 'abc' });
}

That really doesn't look very bad to me. In fact, much of the duplication comes from creating a separate named function object for each action before packaging them into actions. Defining those separately might be important to you, but you can cut down redundancy by defining it directly:
const actions: ActionMap<ActionTypes> = {
    action1: ((payload, trigger) => {
        console.log('action1', payload)
        trigger('action2', { y: 'abc' })
    }),
    action2: ((payload, trigger) => {
        console.log('action2', payload)
        trigger('action1', { x: 123 })
    })
};

This is so terse already that I find it hard to imagine something better that involves using typeof or some other indirection. For example, you could take advantage of the circularity handling of class declarations, by making an ActionsClass class whose instances are your intended actions. Given such a class, you can define the appropriate trigger function utility type:
type ClassTrigger<T> =
    TriggerFunc<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (payload: infer P, ...a: any) => void ? P : never }>

And then define both ActionsClass and the trigger type together:
type ACT = ClassTrigger<ActionsClass>;
class ActionsClass {
    action1(payload: { x: number }, trigger: ACT) {
        console.log('action1', payload);
        trigger('action2', { y: 'abc' });
    };
    action2(payload: { y: string }, trigger: ACT) {
        console.log('action2', payload);
        trigger('action1', { x: 123 })
    }
}
const actions = new ActionsClass();

That achieves the goal of not needing to write action1, action2, {x: number}, or {y: string} more than once (ignoring the calls to trigger(), of course), and with no reliance on an external ActionTypes mapping. But it's so weird, and I'd much rather tell developers to define their types than tell them why they're creating a class when they only need a single instance of it.
Playground link to code
